# A Lovely Moony Message!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge

I like to watch the night sky! One night, standing beside the window, I looked up at the sky. Seemed a little cloudy, but something was unusual. The moon was surrounded by some stars which ... Well, check out yourselves.

```
                                                                    *                      * * * * * *  
     * *   *       *    *       *           * *             *       *                     *             
    *   *  *       *      *       *        *   *            *       *                       *           
     * *    *     *         *       *     *     *           *       *       * * * * *        *          
             * * *            *       *  *       *   * * * *                            * * *           
                                                    o  o             
                                                 o        o        
                                                o          o    
                                                o          o      
                                                 o        o       
                                                    o  o          

        *                                         *                                         
      * *       *  *      *                *    * *                            *  *         
    *   *     *      *    *               *   *   *                          *      *   
        *    *        *   *        *     *        *                         *        *  
        *     *      *    *      *   *  *         *             * * * * *    *      *   
        *       *  *      *     *     *           *                            *  *     


                        *              * *        *                *                        
                          *           *   *       *               *                         
                            *        *     *      *        *     *                          
                              *     *       *     *      *   *  *                           
                                *  *         *    *     *     *                             
                                                          *                         
                                             *   *      * *                         
                        *  *                *    *    *   *      * *                
                      *      *       *     *     *        *     *   *               
                     *        *    *   *  *      *        *      * *    * * * * *   
        * * * * *     *      *    *     *        *        * 
                        *  *
```

**What were the stars telling me?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just

> HURRAY IT'S GOING TO RAIN TONIGHT in [Moon type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_type).

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks for solving :-) +15